# Why does an error message pause code. and how can you stop the code from pausing at the error message in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

Why does a error message in C++ pause the code until the error message is closed out? Here is an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    MessageBox(nullptr, TEXT("Code paused"), TEXT("Code Paused"), MB_OK); // The code pauses at there
    cout << "Code unpaused" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So why does the code pause at the error box, and how can you stop the code from pausing at the error message?

Comment: `MessageBox` creates a modal dialog box.  Modal means the window blocks execution until it is closed.  If you want a modeless dialog box, you'll have to build your own.

Comment: [Modality, part 1: UI-modality vs code-modality](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050218-00/?p=36413).

Comment: This question isn't about C++; it's about Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The `MessageBox` function designed this way, so that it does not return until message is closed.  This design is usually convenient, as it is *modal* dialog, which means that from user's perspective the state of the program does not change, until the box is closed.

Still, program goes not stop. Other threads execute, and the thread that calls `MessageBox` also executes and processes messages of all windows (your windows too, not only message box windows).

So you can move message box to a separate thread, move your other code to a separate thread, move your code to a message handler, or write you own `MessageBox`. Moving your code to a separate thread is the most practical option.

Comment: Don't ignore the first parameter to [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw). Moving that message box to a different thread is just one non-`NULL` argument away from turning *"the most practical option"* into a mess of entanglement you'll never be able to escape again.

Comment: When you move the message box to a separate thread, the message box won't show until you add t.join(); into the code, basically delaying when the message box will show up, and if you don't add t.join(); the code will blast out errors. So how do you move the code to a separate thread _without_ having the code break?

Comment: @MysteryMan386 If you want to be independent of a thread without having the code break, you can use t.detach(). According to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/thread-class?view=vs-2019#detach. But you must ensure that the life cycle of the main function is longer than child thread, otherwise the child thread cannot run correctly.

Comment: @mys A modal dialog blocks the calling code, until the dialog is dismissed. If you want your code to continue executing while the dialog is showing, you'll need a modeless dialog (see [Using Dialog Boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes) for details). Your attempt to run a modal message box on a separate thread appeared to have failed, because returning from `main` terminates the process, including all threads it spawned.

Comment: When I run t.detach(); the code still pauses at the message box, but this time after dismissing the message box the application crashes with this message: abort() has been called. How can you fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to [`MessageBox function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox):It displays a modal dialog box that contains a system icon, a set of buttons, and a brief application-specific message, such as status or error information.

So it creates a modal dialog box, which means that the user needs to obtain the information returned by the dialog box for further operations.

If you want to make a non-blocking dialog box, I recommend you put it in a separate thread.

Here is the sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void fun()
{
    MessageBox(nullptr, TEXT("Code paused"), TEXT("Code Paused"), MB_OK); // The code pauses at there
}

int main() {
    thread t(fun);
    cout << "Code unpaused" << endl;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your thread code is no better, since `join` also blocks execution.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I guess the point was that `cout << "Code unpaused" << endl;` executes before that MessageBox() is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [`detach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/thread-class?view=vs-2019#detach), you need to ensure that the main thread is still working before the child thread ends.

Here is a sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void fun()
{
    MessageBox(nullptr, TEXT("Code paused"), TEXT("Code Paused"), MB_OK); // The code pauses at there
}

int main() 
{
    thread t(fun);
    t.detach();

    cout << "Code unpaused" << endl;

    while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

I added an infinite loop at the end of the main function to ensure that the main thread does not exit. You can use other methods instead.

Here is the output:

[image]